# external css for specific div only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am still a newbie, I have an issue.
I have a website which uses some custom edited `mybootstrap.css`.
I want to add a page by `<?php include 'page.html';?>`

For this `page.html`, I want to use a normal `bootstrap.css`

Now the issue is when i use external css `bootstrap.css` to my `page.html`, it messes the whole page. I want this `bootstrap.css` only for my `page.html` and not for whole website.

I tried to search a lot on Google and StackOverflow, there were 2 possible ways to do it:

First, by creating a `frameset` and the other was

```
`<div>
    <style scoped>
        @import "scoped.css";
    </style>
    enter code here
</div>`
```

Both are not working effectively. Is there any other way? Like using some jquery/javascript for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your CSS will affect only one `<div>` why don't you just copy the class that you want! why do you link the whole sheet!

Answer (score 1):

### you need to add this in the html page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scoped.css">
```

or like this

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scoped.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if i add bootstrap.css it going messing all other div's
thats why i want  external css for specific page or div or class
so that i wont conflict with the other css

Comment: you can do that also dont import or add bootstrap css only add you css like this

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question well, the header/footer of the page is being styled by the CSS you have mentioned. In this case, you could modify your page to contain the header/footer and and `iframe`. The `iframe` would point to a page where an empty header/footer is being used and only the content is being shown. The content will be page.html. This way you will be able to show page.html with the new styles without being worried that the design of the other content of the page will be ruined.

Comment: i have a index.html and i am trying to add a page for which i will be using a default bootstrap.css

but the problem is when i use the default bootstrap.css it messes all the sections in index.html

so i want to use this bootstrap.css only for page.html and shouldnt affect the index.html page.

Comment: @Yuguyo then I understood your question well. You will need to add an iframe to index.html, the iframe should point to a page where only page.html is being loaded and page.html should be responsible to load your particular CSS, which should not affect the other elements of the page. If you have a page inside an iframe, its style will not affect the page which contains the iframe, hence the design will not ruin anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly link your CSS like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scoped.css">
```

Comment: i know how to add the external css,.. all i want to know is .. is the a way i can specifically add external css to only a particular page or particular div

Comment: you can define a class for perticular div like <div clas="test"> and then  write css for it

Answer (score 0):

1. checked that you haven't use some bootstrap classes on your website e.g container, container-fluid, row e.t.c
2. add the bootstrap.css only to page.html and not on your main index file..note that if you include page.html in your index file probably through php include, then your website will inherit some css classes from bootstrap
3. Just like @hamza suggested, you can copy the css styles you neex from boostrap and add it to mycss.css or better still google the css styles you need for the page.html and add it to your css

Comment: that will be too much of work,..
as you said in point number 2 , when i use php include it does inherit the css and messes the index.html all div sections.

thats the reason why i was asking is there any way to use the bootstrap.css only for particular div or particular page

Comment: just check that your website main html is not calling bootstrap classes like i pointed.. but note however that boostrap might interfere with some html like <pre> for example but not to extent of messing up your website

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this **jQuery Scoped CSS plugin**

Include this plugin file (minified, ideally) and call $.scoped() on load. If you add style blocks to the page later, you need to rerun the plugin.

Any style blocks with the scoped attribute are processed and limited to only affect their parent's children:

```
<section>
 <style scoped>
   p {color:red;}
 </style> 
 <p>This will be red.</p>
</section>
```